# Reskinning checkboxes with CSS and Javascript

Tags: html, css, checkbox, accessibility

I have created some simple Javascript to make a checkbox seem re-skinned that hides the checkbox and basically just pulls in a background image through CSS to show the checks/unchecks.

Is this HTML/CSS for hiding the checkbox accessible? I want to be as compliant as possible and am uncertain about the hiding and my label. Currently this is how it looks..

CSS:

```
    .checked:hover, .unchecked:hover
    {
        background-color: #242424;
    }
    .checked
    {
        background-image: url(check.bmp);
        color: #ffb500;
    }
    .unchecked
    {
        background-image: url(unchecked.bmp);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<label for="cbAll" class="checked" id="lblAll">
<input id="cbAll" type="checkbox"  name="cbAll" checked="checked"/>
ALL </label>
```

Comment: edit your title to checkbox not textbox

Comment: Thank you Mark. Must have spaced out, haha.

Comment: Oh, BTW, you can skip the `for` and `id` attributes if `input` is inside `label`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're worried about accessibility, I'd say that looking at others' (especially professionally written) code would be the best. [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) is the one that immediately comes to mind. If you look at the code generated by jQuery UI's button widget, part of whose purpose is to serve as a checkbox replacement.

Original HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" /><label for="check">Toggle</label>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" />
<label for="check" aria-pressed="false" class="[redacted]" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-text">Toggle</span>
</label>
```

Notice the conformation to the [WAI-RIA specification](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria), with the correct use of the `role` attribute to indicate the role taken on by the `label` element as a button (the original `input` element is hidden, and thus ignored by screenreaders). You should have a look at the specifications if you want to know how to build things like this in an accessible manner.

Comment: @Boltclock: jQuery UI adds a lot of `class` es to the elements, all of which are irrelevant here, so I removed them to keep the scrollbar small. But hey, if you want `ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only` added back in I'm always happy to oblige

Comment: @Yi Jiang: nah, I just found your use of `[redacted]` positively funny :P

Comment: Thank you Yi Jiang. That's a very well constructed response, I appreciate the link to the WAI-RIA specification. This will help me with other AJAX like things I might build. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://lipidity.com/fancy-form/

You can see how they do it and incorporate it in your own implementation.

Comment: So it's ok to use labels like I am doing and fine to just hide the input element off the screen when dealing with accessibility? 

Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: As long as you handle different states like :hover :focus, etc so that users can tab through with a keyboard or a mouse and know which element has focus.